# C# Process Execute Bath File (which launches other child processes) with no Console Window

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, process, hide

I need to run a batch file which launches several other processes. I want to run the batch file silently so that no console windows are created. I can run the batch file using:

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "start_system.cmd";
p.Start();

p.WaitForExit();
```

This does not show the console window for `start_system.cmd` but the child processes launched by `start_system.cmd` create console windows. I end up with many console windows on my screen. How can i prevent all those child console windows from showing up?

Its a very long batch script which does a lot of work (not just launching other processes) and i cannot run all the statements from the batch file one by one.

`start_system.cmd` looks like:

```
@echo off
...
lots of environment variables settings
...
call %SDK_DIR%\env\env.cmd
...
other settings
...
call %SDK_DIR%\bin\fs.cmd
...
call %SDK_DIR%\etc\proc.cmd
...
lots of other calls
...
```

Comment: You could start by providing the content of `start_system.cmd`. We cannot realistically help you with batch file related issues, if we cannot see the batch file!

Comment: @Compo I added snippets from the batch file, i cannot paste the whole file because its too long.

Comment: Replace `CALL` with `start "" /min`